# convert time to decimal data type in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, sql-timestamp

[image]

In PostgreSQL / pgadmin -  How do I cast timestamp (HH:MM:SS) as decimal so I can multiply by hourly_rate (XX.YY$) and get total charge_amount?

For the life of me I can't find any reasonably simple solution on Google or this forum.

Can it be that's it's not possible?

Comment: A Postgres timestamp also has a date component.  Can you add sample data to your question?

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean  a `time` type?  Sample data and desired results would clarify.

Comment: Your requirement doesn't make sense, and it sounds like you're confusing the concept of date/time with an interval or duration.

Comment: I added a screenshot snippet to original post.
I need to deduct takeoff time from landing time to get total flight time which I then need to multiply by flight hour cost.
I hope this better explain my issue.
Thanks

Comment: Please provide data as *text*, never as screenshot. Ideally, start with your Postgres version and table definition (`CREATE TABLE` statement).

Comment: first I thank you all for your answers.
I should have mentioned that i'm in my first steps both in PostgreSQL AND this forum so I apologize if don'r follow expected conventions.
that being said, I created this table using the pgadmin GUI and not by writing a "create table" statement so I can't provide the text staement (unless it's written in the background somewere and i'm not aware of it).
I use postgresql 13 and pgadmin 4 v5.2.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are not crossing Midnight:

```
select round((extract(epoch from '15:09:00'::time - '11:53:00'::time)/3600)::numeric, 2) AS duration;
 duration 
----------
     3.27


--Generic form 

select round((extract(epoch from lndg_final_time -  tkof_01_time)/3600)::numeric, 2) AS duration;
```

Personally I would use `timestamp with time zone` for the fields. Then you have 'anchored' times and less confusion especially if you do end up crossing Midnight and/or DST boundaries. You would still subtract the beginning timestamp from the final timestamp to get an interval to extract the epoch from.

Comment: Plus one for suggesting `timestamptz`.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your HMS into seconds and multiply by the (hourlyrate/3600.0). (not debugged) using [EXTRACT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT).

```
EXTRACT (EPOCH FROM timecolumn) * hourlyrate * (1.0/3600.0)
```

If your `timecolumn` also contains date information this computation will yield absurdly large numbers, so be careful. For best results use the interval data type.

Comment: If you do timestamp subtraction e.g `ts_end - ts_begin` you will get an interval that you can extract the epoch from and avoid the large second values.